# How unlock S6 Edge When The Finger Print Scanner is Not Working?

Tags: security, locked-out, samsung-galaxy-s-6, fingerprint

My S6 edge was locked by finger print. It was working fine, but today while I was on bath my child was playing with my mobile and by mistake they tried finger print scanner, now my device is locked out.

Now my device asking for backup password but as the password was alphanumeric (12 digit long), I had also forgot it. I have searched a lot on Google and found that either Google account or resetting the device is only solution.

But I can't even use my Google account as my WiFi and/or mobile data was off when my phone was in lock mode. Now because of Google's security system I can't even enable WiFi or mobile data?

So, my question is:
1. Is there a way to make my device to ask for my finger print once again?
2. or is there a way to on my WiFi or mobile data on lock screen?

Because I don't want to reset my device, as I have unsaved data.

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: Have a look at this comment and see if his works (http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s6/528785-locked-out-galaxy-s6-fingerprint-scanner-passwords-don-t-work.html#post4578198), You probably have already got your phone to work but this is for anyone else who might have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing the power button, till it shows the options like,
power off,
flight mode,
restart,
emergency mode

then select emergency mode. Wait for it to enable. After that, it will ask again for your finger print.